# Run mysqld under a different user (linux)

Tags: mysql, daemon

I've been trying to start mysqld under a different user as well as with a different data path. I've done so by modifing the `my.cnf` file as follows:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/bob/database
socket=/bob/database/mysql.sock
user=bob
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/bob/mysqld.log
pid-file=/bob/mysqld.pid
```

Whenever I try to start the mysql daemon by running `service mysqld start` two things happen

1. I get the following error

   ```
   ERROR: 1005  Can't create table 'db' (errno: 13)
   121010 13:39:46 [ERROR] Aborting
   121010 13:39:46 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
   ```
2. The folder /bob/ and everything in it has mysql:mysql permissions which makes me think the user option in `my.cnf` did not work and because I run the service start command as root it can just chown the dir as mysql:mysql without running into any problems. At the same time when I run that command I get the following warning:

   ```
   121010 13:39:46 [Warning] Ignoring user change to 'mysql' because the user was set to 'bob' earlier on the command line
   ```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

***UPDATE

If instead of having the bob user, I put the mysql user and change the permissions of the bob folder to mysql everything works fine. So this is a problem with changing the user not a different data path.

Comment: Make sure the /bob/ folder has the permissions to read and write

Comment: @Stranger it does. Permissions are 777 for testing purposes.

Comment: if you use centos/redhat it could be a selinux issue.. if you use ubuntu it might be apparmour.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check init script, like /etc/init.d/mysqld or something like that, to see if it initialize mysql database with `mysql` user.

Comment: Yes: in /etc/init.d/mysql, su - mysql -s /bin/bash -c "mysqld_safe > /dev/null &" should be changed to su - bob -s /bin/bash -c "mysqld_safe > /dev/null &"

Answer (score 0):

i think changing the user in the mysql-config has only effect when the mysqld is started during the boot process - see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/changing-mysql-user.html)

Comment: I think what they were trying to say was that if you wanted mysqld to automatically run as that user on startup you would have to change the mysql-config file. Regardless if I restart it, mysql doesn't care if its during boot process or not, it will follow the same steps.

Answer (score 0):

As Jerome explained we have to change one more file

> etc/init.d/mysql
>   `su - mysql -s ...` become `su - bob -s ...`

but with **Ubuntu 18.04** we also need to change this one...

> /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mysql.service
>   `user=mysql` become `user=bob`